# How to find out why my website is slow loading

Tags: asp.net, web, web-hosting

I have an ASP.NET website that is hosted with https://www.blacknight.com/.

Whenever I browse to my website in my browser it can take up to 10 seconds to appear.

How can I determine where the bottleneck is? 
How can I determine if its the web hostings fault or if its due to my own website?
Are there tools that I can use etc

Comment: Does this 10 second startup time occur only the first time you access the application and when you refresh the window it's significantly faster?

Comment: Yes correct Pepto, a refresh is very fast almost instantaneous.

Comment: Let me post my answer below =)

Comment: Did you try using a tool like yslow: http://yslow.org/ or firebug in firefox, which can tell you how long individual requests are taking to load?

Comment: Not yet Brian, I have only used Chrome debugger before to debug javascript but not for this sort of thing as I'm a newbie to this problem and dont know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently when deploying ASP.NET websites to hosting providers the application may become idle and unloaded from memory in a Shared environment. The resulting behavior is that any "new" visits to the website after it's become idle for some time results in a JIT recompilation of the web application before being served again.

Typically hosting providers offer some form of "always on" option for your website which prevents this behavior. Otherwise, in the case of infrequently visited websites, this behavior is par for the course.

Depending on your hosting provider they may respect your web.config entries to allow "Always On" in IIS. You can find more information on this approach [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/443065/how-do-i-prevent-iis-8-from-stopping-idle-asp-net-applications)

Hope this makes sense. It is incredibly common for lower traffic websites in Shared environments.

Answer (score 0):

Well just from looking at your code, you need to change some stuff

First, load the scripts at the end of the body to allow the website to load faster.

One of your CSS if called upon after the body tag, call it inside the head tag.

Also do a resource speed test. Do this easily by going on Google Chrome. Right click, select inspect element, then select Network. Press the red button and reload the page. This will show you how fast the resources are loading. There are also test on pingdom which will show you how fast your website loads and the score of it, it also compares your website to other websites.

But this all may not be the case, it just may be your server. Get a dedicated server with at least 10mpbs. You can also get Cloudflare to speed up the process. Also consider using a CDN to load your website faster.

Good Luck